# Add custom methods to Rails 3.1 asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

How can I add my custom methods to my assets such as css files like Rails did with 'asset_path' helper?

With Rail's own helper, I can write this:

```
# some.css.erb:

<%= asset_path 'a_image.png' %>

# How can I write this:

<%= my_custom_method 'a_image.png' %>
```

I've tried many ways but couldn't found a decent way to this. Do you know one?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way I found was to create a custom helper module in app/helpers:

```
module AssetsHelper
  def my_custom_helper_method
    # do something  
  end
end
```

And then to require it like this in application.rb, after your applications configuration (very bottom):

```
module Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  require Rails.root.join('app', 'helpers', 'assets_helper.rb')
  include AssetsHelper
end
```

And you might follow this issue to find a better way: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3282

Answer (score 0):

Normal helper methods are not available in asset views. To add you own methods you'll need to extend the Sprockets helper module. Have a [look at the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb) of the built-in helpers to see how you might do this.

In a nutshell you can add a file in lib with the same structure as this and add you own methods. Don't forget to include the new library in you application initializer.

Comment: if i add that i hope it would work on heroku too. thanks for the answer. that has been an option for me too. maybe i should fork rails and add this feature myself.