# Rails / Assets pipeline: Dynamically list assets included in a manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, yepnope

I'm successfully using assets pipeline for months.
Now I would like to load some of my JS files asynchronously (using yepnope library). It works well when `config.assets.debug` is `false`.

But in development mode (where `config.assets.debug` is usually `true`), the best option for me would be to dynamically get a list of all js files included in my manifests (I got 2 manifests: application.js and externals.js) to give them to yepnope for async loading.

Any idea to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found the answer, I created this helper (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602173/add-custom-methods-to-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline/8560160#8560160) to see how to declare helper methods visible during asset compilation)

```
# given a list of Sprockets manifests, returns a flattened array of dependency paths
def paths_for_manifests(manifests = [])
  manifests.map do |manifest|
    Rails.application.assets[manifest].dependencies.map{|d| "/assets/#{d.logical_path}"}
  end.flatten
end
```

and I use it like this (from a JS / CoffeeScript file):

```
paths = <%= paths_for_manifests(%w(externals.js application.js)) %>
```