# Encode images into css in Rails' asset pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I was wondering if you could configure the Rails asset pipeline so that the CSS compressor embeds the images referenced in the stylesheets in the resulting production CSS, (i.e. through base64 encoding). Unfortunately even the [Rails guide on the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-compression) has no information about this (or about how to configure anything concerning the compressors).

I know that Rails only provides adapters to common CSS compressors (like YUI), so it's dependent on their capabilities. So if these compressors cannot embed images in CSS, are there any other compressors that can do this and have adapters for Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my (not super large) experience with Rails so far, I'm going to guess that Rails has no support for image data-uri compilation into the CSS. (Which might be why you've found no mention of it in the docs.)

I also can't think of any situations where I'd want to do this; given the potential for image reuse, to compile them directly into the CSS seems like it would invite stylesheet bloat, and the [top Google results I'm seeing](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/) are ambivalent about how useful it is.

How painful for your app is that one extra request? Is it possible that you're [prematurely optimizing](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)?

Comment: Hi, yes you are right, it is an ambivalent topic, I've been reading up on it as well. In my case however I have 10+ small svg graphics (few kilobytes together) referenced in my stylesheets. My css is rather extensive so compiling the svgs into it would have only a comparably small increase, but it would save a good deal of additional requests.

Comment: Got it, that sounds as legit a use case as one could hope for. If I were in that situation I'd first try writing my own Sprockets helper, so in your CSS you can call something like `data_uri_for("image_name.png")` and have Sprockets convert that file into the base64. It looks like [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602173/add-custom-methods-to-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline/8560160#8560160) has a workable approach to that.

Comment: That's indeed the best approach, I didn't think of that. This also enables you to selectively embed assets. I'll try to put something together later. Thanks!

Comment: The right answer is in the comment, but I cannot mark the comment as the correct answer (can I)?