# Rails 4.2: Custom Helper for SCSS Manifest in Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Our application is a collection of 3 engines that make up our base gem. Other plugin gems, written specifically for our base gem, can be used to add functionality to the base.

Currently we have 2 custom sprockets directives and 1 custom Sass importer that attempts to pull in SCSS files from these plugins dynamically into the base manifest. A contrived example looks something like:

```
//= depend_on_gemfile     # mimics default "depend_on" functionality
//= depend_on_stylesheets # mimics default "depend_on" functionality

...

@import 'engine/namespace/settings/global';
@import 'engine/namespace/settings/colors';
@import 'engine/namespace/settings/fonts';
@import '[engine-plugins]/namespace/settings'; # mimics Sass Filesystem importer

...
```

To be clear, this works. We're having problems with the way Sass is caching the files, that is a bit too complicated to get into and not really my goal at the moment.

The point is that we realized that removing the custom Sprockets directives and Sass importer, in favor of using a Rails helper, would also solve our problem, since the ERB would be compiled before the SCSS, we'd be able to find and format all of the paths needed in all included plugins into a string and dump it out into the manifest. Something like:

```
@import 'engine/namespace/settings/global';
@import 'engine/namespace/settings/colors';
@import 'engine/namespace/settings/fonts';
<%= load_plugin_stylesheets_for('settings'); %>

...
```

This seems like a much more simple solution, since all we are doing is finding each path and converting those paths to strings.

The problem seems to be that Rails helpers are outside of domain of Sprockets entirely.

I've found some resources, but they all seem to pertain to Rails 3.

- [Add custom methods to Rails 3.1 asset pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602173/add-custom-methods-to-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline)
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3282

I'm curious if anyone has had this problem with Rails 4, if they solved it and how. Or if I'm just thinking about this all wrong and there is a better way to approach the problem without a similar over-complication like we had before.

**TL;DR**

I'd like to use regular Rails helpers inside of a Sprockets manifest file. The Rails version is 4.2.4. We're running engines. Is this possible?

---

**EDIT:**

[This comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3116#issuecomment-3137131) answered my question.

After implementing this solution in an initializer within our `engine.rb` file, all of the Rails ActionView Helpers were available, including my custom written helper.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue a while ago.

application.scss (within gem) looks like this:

```
 /*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "c3.min";
@import "analytics";
```

and gemspec contains line for including all the code from app folder.

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|    
   s.files = Dir['{app,config,db,lib}/**/*', 'MIT-LICENSE', 'Rakefile',   'README.rdoc']
end
```

Be sure to check that you don't have any caching enabled in env files as well.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I found another solution that fit my use case a bit better. I linked to in my original post.